# How to upload file into s3 from ec2 using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an web app that is hosted on ec2 ubuntu 22.04, and using PHP I want to upload a file to s3, I created an AMI role with s3fullAccess and is attached to the ec2.

This is the upload file

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;  
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
$bucket = 'bucket-name'; 
 
 
$statusMsg = ''; 
$status = 'danger'; 
 
// If file upload form is submitted 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ 
    // Check whether user inputs are empty 
    if(!empty($_FILES["userfile"]["name"])) { 
        // File info 
        $file_name = basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]); 
        $file_type = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
         
        // Allow certain file formats 
        $allowTypes = array('xlsx'); 
        if(in_array($file_type, $allowTypes)){ 
            // File temp source 
            $file_temp_src = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]; 
             
            if(is_uploaded_file($file_temp_src)){ 
                // Instantiate an Amazon S3 client 
                $s3Client = new S3Client([
                    'region' => 'eu-central-1',
                    'version' => '2006-03-01'
                ]);
                
 
                // Upload file to S3 bucket 
                try { 
                    $result = $s3->putObject([ 
                        'Bucket' => $bucket, 
                        'Key'    => $file_name,
                        'SourceFile' => $file_temp_src 
                    ]); 
                    $result_arr = $result->toArray(); 
                     
                    if(!empty($result_arr['ObjectURL'])) { 
                        $s3_file_link = $result_arr['ObjectURL']; 
                    } else { 
                        $api_error = 'Upload Failed! S3 Object URL not found.'; 
                    } 
                } catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) { 
                    $api_error = $e->getMessage(); 
                } 
                 
                if(empty($api_error)){ 
                    $status = 'success'; 
                    $statusMsg = "File was uploaded to the S3 bucket successfully!"; 
                }else{ 
                    $statusMsg = $api_error; 
                } 
            }else{ 
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed!"; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only Word/Excel/Image files are allowed to upload.'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.'; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

This is the html file

```
 <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Select File:</b></label>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Upload">
    </div>
    </form>
```

when i try to upload a file is just loading until it get connection time out. How can i solve this, I can only use the role attached to the ec2 as credentials because i cant create users.

Comment: Is your instance in a private subnet?

Comment: @FilippoTestini yes

Answer (score 0):

Given that your EC2 instance is located in a private subnet, having S3 full access is not sufficient. You will need to enable the connection from your instance to your bucket using either a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or a [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html).

Please note that using a NAT Gateway means the traffic will traverse the public internet, whereas using a VPC Endpoint ensures the traffic will only traverse the AWS infrastructure.

In terms of costs, the VPC endpoint might be the most cost-effective solution in your case, especially if you only need to access S3 and no other public services. Here is a breakdown of the costs:

- **NAT Gateway**: $0.045/hour → $1.08/day
- **S3 Interface Endpoint**: $0.01/hour → $0.24/day